# TensorFlow how to separate building from executing for data parallelism

Tags: python, tensorflow

In TensorFlow usually modules are encapsulated in functions or classes and abstract the creation of the needed variables to call them for example

```
net = slim.fully_connected(inputs=input, num_output=neurons ..)
net = tf.layers.conv2d(net, num_filters, filter_size ..)
```

Here the weights and biases for each of each operation will be created at first and then reused.

When we want to achieve data parallelism we want the variables to be created and stored on the CPU, and then sent into the GPUs along with the data, like in the following diagram

[image]

In the [cifar10_multi_gpu_train](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) example you can see that they don't use the `tf.layers` if you examine `cifar10.py` on the same directory you'll see that they use the lower level operations of `fully_connected` and `conv2d` and manually create the kernels, weights and biases on the CPU.
This could be very cumbersome if we want to use complicated structures that are already implemented for ease of use in TensorFlow.

My question is: Can we use high level module abstractions (from `slim`/`tf.layers` and others that abstract the variables creation) in a fashion where the variables will be created on the CPU but the operations will execute on GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

About pinning the variables to the CPU, you can do that with [`tf.device`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/device) and a device function. In distributed environments you have [`tf.train.replica_device_setter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/replica_device_setter), but it is easy to do something similar for the local case:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def my_device_placement(device, vars_device='/cpu:0'):
    # Ops to pin on the CPU
    VAR_TYPES = ['Variable', 'VariableV2', 'VarHandleOp']
    def device_function(op):
        return vars_device if op.type in VAR_TYPES else device
    return device_function

def conv2d_replica(input_, filters, kernel_size, name, device, is_first_replica):
    with tf.device(my_device_placement(device)):
        return tf.layers.conv2d(input_, filters, kernel_size, name=name, reuse=not is_first_replica)

inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 100, 100, 3])
lyr1 = conv2d_replica(inp, 5, [20, 20], 'Layer', '/gpu:0', True)
lyr2 = conv2d_replica(inp, 5, [20, 20], 'Layer', '/gpu:1', False)
print('Device of first replica:', lyr1.device)
print('Device of second replica:', lyr2.device)
print('Variable devices:')
for var in tf.trainable_variables():
    print(var.name, var.device)
```

Output:

```
Device of first replica: /gpu:0
Device of second replica: /gpu:1
Variable devices:
Layer/kernel:0 /cpu:0
Layer/bias:0 /cpu:0
```

The ops that should go on the CPU is for you to decide. You can look at `STANDARD_PS_OPS` in [`python/training/device_setter.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.10.1/tensorflow/python/training/device_setter.py) to see what TensorFlow considers to be the standard set of operations pinned to a parameter server (in this case it is local, but the idea is similar).

---

With `tf.layers`, you can use the `name` and `reuse` parameters. When `reuse=True`, the layer will use the weights of a previously created layer with the same `name`. Note this means that the first time you create the layer `reuse` should be `False`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 100, 100, 3])
lyr1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inp, 5, [20, 20], name='Layer', reuse=False)
lyr2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inp, 5, [20, 20], name='Layer', reuse=True)
```

Graph:

[image: Model 1]

Here the `BiasAdd` nodes are the outputs of the layer. The weights are created within the same layer and reused in the second one.

Note that this works even across namespaces (I am not sure whether this is intended or not, as I have not found explicit documentation about it):

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 100, 100, 3])
with tf.name_scope('Replica1'):
    lyr1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inp, 5, [20, 20], name='Layer', reuse=False)
with tf.name_scope('Replica2'):
    lyr2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inp, 5, [20, 20], name='Layer', reuse=True)
```

Graph:

[image: Model 2]

Note: Even though nowadays it is basically deprecated, it seems that `tf.slim` also offers the same functionality. In this case there is a `reuse` parameter too and then a `scope` parameter for the variable scope, so it would be something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
with tf.variable_scope('Layer') as scope:
    lyr1 = tf.contrib.slim.fully_connected(inp, 5, reuse=False, scope=scope)
with tf.variable_scope('Layer') as scope:
    lyr2 = tf.contrib.slim.fully_connected(inp, 5, reuse=True, scope=scope)
```

Comment: amm.. I don't see the separation, you basically run the layer on the inputs once on the CPU and then use the save layer on the GPU - I don't want to ever make a pass through the layer on the CPU - just build the vars on it and make the pass on the GPU

Comment: @bluesummers I thought your issue was about reusing the same variables for different calls to `tf.layers.conv2d`, not about device pinning. You should be able to do that with a device function, I'll update the answer...

Comment: For specific example, my question is for `tf.layers.conv2d` is how do I create the kernels and biases on the CPU, but use them and perform the convolution on GPUs? Separating the `tf.device` of the variable creation and operation calling

Comment: @bluesummers I have edited the answer, see if that helps with your case.

Comment: The edit does seem on point, and quite elegant. Are we sure that `['Variable', 'VariableV2']` will capture all possible variables no matter what I throw at it?

Comment: @bluesummers Actually I'm finding this was covered in the [Performance Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#optimizing_for_gpu), I added `VarHandleOp`. The linked source code includes a bunch more of them (`AutoReloadVariable`, `MutableHashTable`, `MutableHashTableV2`, `MutableHashTableOfTensors`, `MutableHashTableOfTensorsV2`, `MutableDenseHashTable`, `MutableDenseHashTableV2`, `BoostedTreesEnsembleResourceHandleOp`), I suppose that's every mutable type but their usage seems less common... maybe add `AutoReloadVariable` just in case? (I don't really know what it is)

Comment: Or just do `from tensorflow.python.training.device_setter import STANDARD_PS_OPS` and use that list...